# AWS Workspaces - Unable to provide Console Access to IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-workspaces

I want an IAM user to have read/List access and start/stop access to AWS workspaces. Hence I've created a simple IAM policy which grants all read and list actions.
[image: Workspaces]

but this was not enough. I was displayed with an error message `An Error Has Occurred There was an error retrieving information about your WorkSpaces.` Upon investigating cloudtrail, I found that the user need read/list permissions to KMS and AWSDirectory Service. Hence granted that too but when I login again, I still see the same error. Even tried attaching EC2 full access too but still the same error. Is this a potential bug?
The same issue has been discussed in AWS forum too but no resolution there.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236408

KMS policy and Directory service policy below.

**DS:**
[image: Directory-Service]

**KMS:**
[image: KMS]

**Error Screenshot:**
[image: Error]

Comment: Did you follow the displayed link ("this document") to see what it suggested?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've posted the answer below. looks like there is a weird limitation on AWS side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution for this. AWS has bizarre limitation where if you want to access workspaces via console, then you need to give full access (`workspaces:*`) only. Below is a screenshot from the document that states this. Highly disappointed with AWS regarding this limitation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-access-control.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a policy similar to the one [in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/workspaces-access-control.html). It includes some services in addition to the once you have tried already.

Comment: I've found the answer. you can see my answer. looks like there is a bizarre limitation on AWS side.

Comment: Ah, so it was specifically a console issue? Thanks for sharing.